# Does Spring Cloud Feign support placeholders in Spring MVC annotations?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-netflix

I'd like to use a placeholder to define the path of a request as shown below. When I attempt the request its seems that spring-cloud-feign is unable to swap the placeholder with an application.yml value.

```
@FeignClient("foo")
public interface FooClient{
    @RequestMapping(value = "${my.special.placeholder}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity getSomeData(s);
}
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @spencergibb I'm using 1.1.0.M5

Comment: I don't believe it does. It works on `@FeignClient`. File an issue if you'd like.

Comment: I've create an issue for this feature in the link below. Thank you for help @spencergibb.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/894